# Query to get Woo products in a parent-children order

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, variable-product

I want to build a MySQL query for a Woo database schema to get simple/variable products, but in a specific order: I want to get them in an `ID` `ASC`ending order, but when a variable product is met, I want to get the variations exactly below their parent.

So for a simple product, or the parent of a variable product, the `post_type` field is set to 'product' and the `post_parent` field is set to 0. For the children of a variable product (a.k.a variations) the `post_type` field is set to 'variable_product' and the `post_parent` field is set to the `ID` of the parent product.

So, imagine this desired order:

| ID | post_title | post_type | post_parent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1100 | title1 | product | 0 |
| 1104 | title2 | product | 0 |
| 1130 | title2 - variation1 | variable_product | 1104 |
| 1200 | title2 - variation2 | variable_product | 1104 |
| 1208 | title2 - variation3 | variable_product | 1104 |
| 1107 | title3 | product | 0 |
| 1111 | title4 | product | 0 |
| 1205 | title4 - variation1 | variable_product | 1111 |
| 1210 | title4 - variation4 | variable_product | 1111 |
| 1430 | title4 - variation3 | variable_product | 1111 |
| 1432 | title4 - variation2 | variable_product | 1111 |

So by the above table you see that I want products to be sorted by their ID, until the variation(s) of a product are met, which I want to be placed under their parent, and get sorted themselves by their ID also. So I don't care about titles not being sorted alphabetically (title4-variation4 is sorted above title4 - variation3 because the variations' IDs are sorted in an ascending order).

So I tried to play a little with `ORDER BY ID ASC, post_parent ASC` and also `ORDER BY ID ASC, post_type ASC` because product is sorted alphabetically above variation_product, but I couldn't get them sorted correctly. I always end up with parent products being sorted higher than variations, just because their IDs are smaller.

`SELECT * FROM wp6c_posts WHERE post_type IN ('product', 'product_variation') ORDER BY ID ASC, post_parent ASC;`

Obviously I have to query table wp6c_posts twice, once for the simple/parent products, and then for the variations of the variable products, but I can't think of the correct query.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following query. It may fulfils your requirement.

```
  $args = array(
        'post_per_page' => 1,
        'order'         => 'DESC',
        'post_type'     => ['product', 'variable_product'],
    );

    $products = get_children($args);

    if ($products) {
        foreach ($products as $product) {

        }
    }
```